# How to resolve this error 407 during login?

Tags: python, django

I tried to check by printing where could be the cause of the problem. It shows that user_id and password were there but it cannot proceed after that.

```
def login_request(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    user_id = request.POST['user_id']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(user_id=user_id, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return redirect("/index")
    else:
        messages.info(request, 'Invalid Credentials')
    return redirect('login_request')
else:
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

urls.py
    path('login_request/', views.login_request, name='login_request'),

Answer (score 1):

You need to authenticate user with *username* and *password* not with user_id

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request,username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return redirect("/index")
    else:
        messages.info(request, 'Invalid Credentials')
        return redirect('login_request')
else:
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```